# PHP mb_ereg_replace not replacing while preg_replace works as intended

Tags: php, regex, pcre, multibyte

I am trying to replace in a string all non word characters with empty string expect for spaces and the put together all multiple spaces as one single space.

Following code does this.

```
$cleanedString = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', ' ', $name);  
$cleanedString = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $cleanedString);
```

But when I am trying to use mb_ereg_replace nothing happens.

```
$cleanedString = mb_ereg_replace('/[^\w]/', ' ', $name);  
$cleanedString = mb_ereg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $cleanedString);
```

$cleanedString is same as of that if $name in the above case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mb_ereg_replace` doesn't use separators. You may or may not also have to specify the encoding before.

```
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
//regex could also be \W
$cleanedString = mb_ereg_replace('[^\w]', ' ', $name);
$cleanedString = mb_ereg_replace('\s+', ' ', $cleanedString);
```

Comment: Thanks that was the mistake I did.
If my input is UTF-8 is there any recommendation regarding which method to use?

Comment: @Jithin If it's UTF-8, you might as well use `preg_replace` with the `u` flag: `preg_replace('/\s+/u', ' ', $cleanedString);`

Comment: @Artefacto Thanks. Can you please tell me if it is safe to assume that as long as input is in UTF-8 encoding, the preg_replace will work for most languages?

Comment: @Jithin Depends on what you mean with "works". It will work in a strict sense -- won't generate corrupted data, but it probably doesn't do what you want. Consider the first regex. In PCRE (the engine `preg_replace` uses), `\w` will only mean `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. If you want to eliminate all non-word characters, a better option is to use `[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}_]`. This will match all characters that are not (per Unicode) letters, non-spacing marks (for accents, etc), decimal digits and the underscore.

Comment: @Artefacto  Thanks. Won't \w will match characters depending on the current locale. So based on the language of the input string if I change the locale (using setlocale()) won't it work. Or is the approach wrong? 

When running in the context of a web server like apache I do not know if locale is influenced by the base system setting or depending in the input request.

Comment: @Jithin No, it's locale independent.

Comment: @Artefacto . Thanks again. But I read that for PCRE \w depends on locale. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Backslashed-sequences

Comment: SORRY My Bad. I was looking at wrong documentation. It was for perl. :D

Comment: @Jithin See the man page for PCRE [here](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt), "General comments about UTF-8 mode", point 6.

Comment: @Artefacto Many Many thanks. One more doubt. Is mb_ereg_replace using PCRE ? Does regex pattern behaves same with mb_ereg_replace?

Comment: @Jithin No. It uses [oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/). By default, `\w` means (Letter|Mark|Number|Connector_Punctuation).

Comment: @Artefacto Hmm so much to learn. :| . From the documentation http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt, it looks like for unicode input \w can give true work boundary.  

Is there any recommendation on usage between preg_replace and mb_ereg_replace?But I guess preg_replace being natively available in php could be faster.

Comment: @Jithin They're both "natively available" (well, actually PCRE cannot be left out in PHP 5.3, but that shouldn't influence the speed). However, you'll find that PHP's PCRE interface functions (preg_ family) are both easier to use and more well-documented. If I had to guess, I'd say PCRE is also faster.

Comment: @Artefacto I faced a different issue with respect to characters containing horizontal spaces.    [^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}_] had to be modified to     [^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}_] for matching spacing marks also.

I asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598212/php-vim--bangalore-has-a-break-before-the-last-character-

Answer (score -1):

```
function create_slug_html($string, $ext='.html'){     
   $replace = '-';         
   $string=strtolower($string);     
   $string=trim($string);

    mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
    //regex could also be \W
    $string= mb_ereg_replace('[^\w]', ' ', $string);
    $string= mb_ereg_replace('\s+', ' ', $string);

   //remove query string     
   if(preg_match("#^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-_.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}#i",$string)){         
         $parsed_url = parse_url($string);         
         $string = $parsed_url['host'].' '.$parsed_url['path'];         
         //if want to add scheme eg. http, https than uncomment next line         
         //$string = $parsed_url['scheme'].' '.$string;     
   }      
   //replace / and . with white space     
   $string = preg_replace("/[\/\.]/", " ", $string);   

   // $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);  

   //remove multiple dashes or whitespaces     
   $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);   

   //convert whitespaces and underscore to $replace     
   $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $replace, $string);     
   //limit the slug size     
   $string = substr($string, 0, 200);     
   //slug is generated     
   return ($ext) ? $string.$ext : $string;
```

}

please check is it ok and support english and unicode

Comment: While code-only answers are not forbidden, please understand that this is a Q&A community, rather than a crowd-sourcing one, and that, usually, if the OP understood the code being posted as an answer, he/she would have come up with a similar solution on his/her own, and wouldn't have posted a question in the first place. As such, please provide context to your answer and/or code by explaining *how* and/or *why* it works.

Answer (score -5):

The input is not [Multi-Byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding) hence the `mb` function fails.

Comment: ok. But can you please explain when we should use mb_ereg_replace instead of preg_replace if my input is in UTF-8. 

Currently I passed english text as $name. But if tomorrow I use some other language say Hindi will my code break ?

Comment: Wrong. The multibyte extension can handle single byte encodings.