# php + vim - बंगलौर (Bangalore) has a break before the last character र

Tags: php, regex, vim, unicode, hindi

I used http://translate.google.com/#en|hi|Bangalore to get the Hindi for Bangalore and बंगलौर.

But when I pasted it in vim there is a break before the last character र.
I am using preg_replace with the regex pattern **/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}_]/u** for matching words. But this is treating the last character as a separate word.

This is my input string मैनेजमेंट, बंगलौर and I am expecting the output to be मैनेजमेंट  बंगलौर after the preg_replace

```
$cleanedString = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}_]/u', ' ', $name);
```

But the output I am getting is मैनेजमेंट  बंगल र . What am I doing wrong here? I guess the problem starts from how vim handled the text I pasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex `"/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}_]/u"`

The `O` symbol in `लौ` takes extra horizontal space as opposed to the `ae` in `मै`. The unicode class `\p{Mn}` matches only non-spacing marks. Use `\p{Mc}` to match spacing-marks. You can use `\p{M}` to match all combining-marks: `"/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{M}_]/u"`

From [regular-expressions.info/unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

> `\p{M}` or `\p{Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).
>
> - `\p{Mn}` or `\p{Non_Spacing_Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character without taking up extra space (e.g. accents, umlauts, etc.).
> - `\p{Mc}` or `\p{Spacing_Combining_Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character that takes up extra space (vowel signs in many Eastern languages).
> - `\p{Me}` or `\p{Enclosing_Mark}`: a character that encloses the character is is combined with (circle, square, keycap, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to match all words in the input string in UTF-8 which ever language they may be in. The regex    "/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}_]/u" helped

Comment: I also noticed something in vim. vim seems to have some trouble in detecting the correct word end for the बंगलौर

Comment: @Jithin can you elaborate on that - may be as a new question if needed?

Comment: In vim if I press w if should I ideally move to next words beginning. But for बंगलौर w from the start moves to र .

Comment: @Jithin What about other Hindi words - is it only for bangalore or words ending with `r` or for all indic words?