# php preg_replace issue while replacing several words

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, words

i have the following regular expression:

```
$patterns = array
(
    '/\b(gubalowka hegy)\b/i',
    '/\b(krakkó|wawel|wawelban|auschwitz|auschwitzba|auschwitz-birkenua)\b/i',
    '/\b(királyi|város|fogaskerekű|séta)\b/i',
);

$replaces = array
(
    '<strong>$1</strong>',
    '<u><em>$1</em></u>',
    '<strong>$1</strong>',
);

preg_replace($patterns, $replaces, $text);
```

The problem is, that only some words gets replaced.

By this example only these words:

```
Séta               => <strong>Séta</strong>
Krakkó             => <u><em>Krakkó</em></u>
királyi            => <strong>királyi</strong>
Auschwitz-Birkenua => <u><em>Auschwitz-Birkenua</em></u>
```

The other words stay untouched.

I tried to get it working several ways (replacing every word seperately, replacing group of words without arrays) but neither of them worked.

Here you can check it:
http://adriaholiday.dev.webndev.hu/ajanlatok/lengyelorszagi-hetvege.html

The regular expressions get logged in chrome dev console

Could somebody help ? Thank you.

## Edit:

If I write the regex, it works

```
$pattern = '/\b(krakkó|wawel|wawelban|auschwitz|auschwitzba)\b/iu'
$replace = '<strong><u>$1</u></strong>';
$text    = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

the issue appears only when the regex gets generated

```
$replace = '<strong>$1</strong>';

foreach (...)
{
    $words .= "|{$word}"; // first vertical bar removed ...
}

// encoding UTF8
// pattern: /\b(krakkó|wawel|wawelban|auschwitz|auschwitzba)\b/iu
$pattern = '/\b(' . $words . ')\b/iu';

$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: This could be an issue with ascii vs unicode - I haven't done much with php regex for a long time but that might be an area to look. How well does php handle case insensitive unicode strings?

Comment: add `u` to your modifiers (`/foo/iu`) to tell PCRE to treat the pattern as UTF-8. see http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: i tried "u" already, it doesn't help

Comment: after concatenation, $word has an wrong remaining pipe!!! also, as other mention, "u" modifier is needed

Comment: the $pattern variable contains: /\b(krakkó|wawel|wawelban|auschwitz|auschwitzba)\b/iu

Answer (score 1):

Check if mbstring and mbregex is available. PHP's default type, `ISO-8859-1` does not include ő, ű , Ő and Ű and other special chars (but I'm assuming you'll only need these). `UTF-8` does, but you'll have to use multibyte functions with that.

To read more on mbstring, look at [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php). It inclueds mb_ereg_replace as well.

**EDIT**: I found out that with the u flag, preg_repace can use UTF-8 as well. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594627/php-mb-ereg-replace-not-replacing-while-preg-replace-works-as-intended).

Comment: I tried it with the u flag, but it doesn't change anything, i try now with mb_ereg_replace