# Make mb_ereg_replace case insensitive and use other regex? (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, multibyte

I have a few regex patters which I want to use now for the multibyte preg_replace function. I already found out that mb_ereg_replace is not using separators:

[PHP mb_ereg_replace not replacing while preg_replace works as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594627/php-mb-ereg-replace-not-replacing-while-preg-replace-works-as-intended)

My question is now, after I got my mb_ereg_replace function worked with \b how can I make it also case insensitive? My actual code is:

```
$myTitle = 'Wie geht es dir';

$string = mb_ereg_replace('\bWie geht es dir\b/i', 'Hat geklappt ', $myTitle);

echo $string;
```

But with `/i` it is not working. So here are my questions:

1. How can I use `/i` at mb_ereg_replace or how can I make the pattern case insensitive?
2. I also need those patterns for mb_ereg_replace but have no idea...? - Can somebody please help me? - I have now idea of mb_ereg_replace...

   1. `trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $string)))`
   2. `preg_replace('~\b(?:' . implode('|', $delete) . ')\b~i', '', $string);`
   3. As descibed above, I need also a case insensitive pattern...

I would be very grateful about help :)
Greetings and Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mb_eregi_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php) php function.

> mb_eregi_replace — Replace regular expression with multibyte support ignoring case

Or use [`mb_ereg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php#refsect1-function.mb-ereg-replace-parameters) with the option **i** as last parameter :

```
$string = mb_ereg_replace('\bWie geht es dir\b', 'Hat geklappt ', $myTitle, 'i');
```

From php manual (`mb_ereg_remplace()` last parameter) :

> ### option
>
> Matching condition can be set by option parameter. If i is specified for this parameter, the case will be ignored. If x is specified, white space will be ignored. If m is specified, match will be executed in multiline mode and line break will be included in '.'. If p is specified, match will be executed in POSIX mode, line break will be considered as normal character. If e is specified, replacement string will be evaluated as PHP expression.

Hope it helps.

### **EDIT**

For question #2 :

Yes, those patterns will work with `mb_ereg_replace()` and `mb_eregi_replace()`. Just no need to use delimiters in the patterns.

i.e. :

#### 1. `trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $string)));`

Will be :

```
trim(mb_ereg_replace('\s\s+', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $string), 'i'));
// or
trim(mb_eregi_replace('\s\s+', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $string)));
```

#### 2. `preg_replace('~\b(?:' . implode('|', $delete) . ')\b~i', '', $string);`

Will be :

```
mb_ereg_replace('\b(?:' . implode('|', $delete) . ')\b', '', $string, 'i');
// or
mb_eregi_replace('\b(?:' . implode('|', $delete) . ')\b', '', $string);
```

Comment: I guest, yes. Just give them a try with `mb_ereg_replace`.

Comment: @Jan and if you get some errors while use them with `mb_ereg_replace()` just ask another question.

Comment: We are talking about mb_ereg_replace()? - what do you mean?

Comment: I'm talking about the question #2. at point #1 & #2 : you could just give those patterns a try with `mb_ereg_replace()` (with **i** as last parameter for case insensitive) or with `mb_eregi_replace()`. It must work.

Comment: @Jan I edited my post with the answer for your question #2. If it solved your question, thank for validate my answer. ; )